# Mangopay NodeJS integration

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to create new user using user rest API.

I'm using following SDK for my NodeJS app.

`https://github.com/larafale/mangopay`

With following configuration

```
{
    username: 'bundle',
    password: '{my password used when I login to this dashboard}',
    production: false
}
```

But I'm getting following error.

`https://www.dropbox.com/s/gjk0l6n6g3glrys/mangopay.PNG?dl=0`

What is the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The username corresponds to the **clientId** and the password to the **passphrase**. You should have received these informations by email when you subscribed.